# Is there a way to ignore empty nodes in JAXB bindings file?

Tags: jaxb, xjc, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I am trying to create a generic `.xjb` bindings file to provide consistent Java classes generation from WSDLs / XSDs across multiple projects.
We generate the code via `maven-jaxb2-plugin` (Made by @lexicore).

The problem lies in the *multiple projects* part. If a particular binding instruction matches nothing in the provided XSD or WSDL, the class generation fails with

> XPath evaluation of "`<some_xpath_expression>`" results in empty target node

**How can I tell JAXB to ignore these cases so the bindings file can be used on any project without fine-tuning, regardless of the elements types used?**

Here is a (stripped down) version showcasing the problem I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jxb:bindings xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" version="2.1"                
              xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
              xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
              jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc">
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="path/to/the/schema" node="/xs:schema">
        <jxb:bindings multiple="true" node="//*[@type='xs:dateTime']">
            <xjc:javaType name="java.time.LocalDateTime" adapter="a.b.c.LocalDateTimeAdapter" />
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

If I try to generate classes from a schema with no `dateTime` element, it will fail.

The objective is, in the end, to create something all projects of various teams could reuse without changing anything but the `schemaLocation`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the **required="no"** attribute on the binding that you would like to allow not to match any node, i.e.

```
<jxb:bindings required="no" multiple="true" node="//*[@type='xs:dateTime']">
```

Depending on your context you may choose to say **required="false"** or **required="0"** as well.